# Redirect traffic from a pysical interface to another

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) with two physical network interfaces. One of them is connected to my router which provides Internet access. My idea is to share the Internet to another device via the second physical interface.

How can I redirect traffic from a pysical interface to another?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking and what you mean to ask are probably 2 different things, and in fact "How can I redirect traffic from a pysical interface to another?" makes little sense.

There are 2 types of options depending on your intent -

**BRIDGING**

The first is to bridge the 2 interfaces to create a virtual switch/hub, which makes (IP) traffic the Pi invisible to the router and server when traffic is destined for the other device.  To do this, get the bridge-utils package, and edit /etc/network/interfaces with commands like

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    pre-up ip link set eth0 down
    pre-up ip link set eth1 down
    pre-up brctl addbr br0
    pre-up brctl addif br0 eth0 eth10
    pre-up ip addr flush dev eth0
    pre-up ip addr flush dev eth1
    post-down ip link set eth0 down
    post-down ip link set eth1 down
    post-down ip link set br0 down
    post-down brctl delif br0 eth0 eth1
    post-down brctl delbr br0
```

You will then have a br0 interface which will act as the local interface for the device, and eth0 and eth1 will act as a switch as well.

**ROUTING**

If you want to turn your device into a router, and have the second interface have its traffic rewritten as coming  from the Pi, you need to do routing.

First step is to enable forwarding - you can modify the line "net.ipv4.ip_forward" to have a value of "1" in /etc/sysctl.conf, then run sysctl -p to load the change (or reboot the PI).

The second step would be to bring up the interfaces on the Pi with appropriate IP addresses.  The IP addresses need to be in different subnets with correct subnet masks.  If you are running DHCP, set up a DHCP server on the Pi. (otherwise you can statically assign addresses).

Then add a rule like 
iptables -t nat -A PPOSTROUTING -o ethX -j MASQUERADE

The "ethX" is the Interface connected to the connection with Internet - this rewrites the packets so that from the routers POV they come from the PI rather then the device plugged into it.

(The above is an overview only - you can draw a lot from the online tutorials about converting a Pi into a Wifi bridge and Wifi router respectively, leaving out the WIFI specific bits and changing the interface names as appropriate).